# Train loss is decreasing, but accuracy remain the same

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, classification, bert-language-model

this is the train and development cell for multi-label classification task using Roberta (BERT). the first part is training and second part is development (validation). train_dataloader is my train dataset and dev_dataloader is development dataset. my question is: why train loss is decreasing step by step, but accuracy doesn't increase so much? practically, accuracy is increasing until iterate 4, but train loss is decreasing until the last epoch (iterate). is this ok or there should be a problem?

```
train_loss_set = []
iterate = 4
for _ in trange(iterate, desc="Iterate"):
  model.train()

  train_loss = 0 
  nu_train_examples, nu_train_steps = 0, 0
  
  for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    batch_input_ids, batch_input_mask, batch_labels = batch
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(batch_input_ids, attention_mask=batch_input_mask)
    logits = output[0]
    loss_function = BCEWithLogitsLoss() 
    loss = loss_function(logits.view(-1,num_labels),batch_labels.type_as(logits).view(-1,num_labels))
    train_loss_set.append(loss.item())    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    train_loss += loss.item()
    nu_train_examples += batch_input_ids.size(0)
    nu_train_steps += 1

  print("Train loss: {}".format(train_loss/nu_train_steps))

###############################################################################

  model.eval()
  logits_pred,true_labels,pred_labels,tokenized_texts = [],[],[],[]

  # Predict
  for i, batch in enumerate(dev_dataloader):
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    batch_input_ids, batch_input_mask, batch_labels = batch
    with torch.no_grad():
      out = model(batch_input_ids, attention_mask=batch_input_mask)
      batch_logit_pred = out[0]
      pred_label = torch.sigmoid(batch_logit_pred)
      batch_logit_pred = batch_logit_pred.detach().cpu().numpy()
      pred_label = pred_label.to('cpu').numpy()
      batch_labels = batch_labels.to('cpu').numpy()

    tokenized_texts.append(batch_input_ids)
    logits_pred.append(batch_logit_pred)
    true_labels.append(batch_labels)
    pred_labels.append(pred_label)

  pred_labels = [item for sublist in pred_labels for item in sublist]
  true_labels = [item for sublist in true_labels for item in sublist]
  threshold = 0.4
  pred_bools = [pl>threshold for pl in pred_labels]
  true_bools = [tl==1 for tl in true_labels]
  
  print("Accuracy is: ", jaccard_score(true_bools,pred_bools,average='samples'))
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'bert_model')
```

and the outputs:

```
Iterate:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Train loss: 0.4024542534684801

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Jaccard is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in samples with no true or predicted labels. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))

Accuracy is:  0.5806403013182674

Iterate:  10%|█         | 1/10 [03:21<30:14, 201.64s/it]

Train loss: 0.2972540049911379
Accuracy is:  0.6091337099811676

Iterate:  20%|██        | 2/10 [06:49<27:07, 203.49s/it]

Train loss: 0.26178574864264137
Accuracy is:  0.608361581920904

Iterate:  30%|███       | 3/10 [10:17<23:53, 204.78s/it]

Train loss: 0.23612180122962365
Accuracy is:  0.6096717783158462

Iterate:  40%|████      | 4/10 [13:44<20:33, 205.66s/it]

Train loss: 0.21416303515434265
Accuracy is:  0.6046892655367231

Iterate:  50%|█████     | 5/10 [17:12<17:11, 206.27s/it]

Train loss: 0.1929110718982203
Accuracy is:  0.6030885122410546

Iterate:  60%|██████    | 6/10 [20:40<13:46, 206.74s/it]

Train loss: 0.17280191068465894
Accuracy is:  0.6003766478342749

Iterate:  70%|███████   | 7/10 [24:08<10:21, 207.04s/it]

Train loss: 0.1517329115446631
Accuracy is:  0.5864783427495291

Iterate:  80%|████████  | 8/10 [27:35<06:54, 207.23s/it]

Train loss: 0.12957811209705325
Accuracy is:  0.5818832391713747

Iterate:  90%|█████████ | 9/10 [31:03<03:27, 207.39s/it]

Train loss: 0.11256680189521162
Accuracy is:  0.5796045197740114

Iterate: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [34:31<00:00, 207.14s/it]
```

Comment: I would suggest that it is most likely that beyond your 4th iteration you are just over-training the model.

Comment: Thanks, you mean that 4 epochs are enough?

Comment: @magazvazn - The answer is a maybe, but it is my suspicion that in this case continued reduction in train loss no longer has a material impact on accuracy.  Further epochs are not materially changing the weights, and hence are having little impact on your model's predictive capabilities.
This is of course, dependent on batch size, model structure, initializers, etc.

Comment: Thanks bro. i just wanted to know if i did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The training loss is decreasing because you model gradually learns your training set. The evaluation accuracy is how well the model learned the global features of your training set and how well your model predicts "unseen data". So, if the loss is decreasing, your model is learning. Perhaps it has learned too specific information from the training set and it is, in fact, overfitting. This means that it fits "too well" to the training data and is unable to make correct predictions on unseen data, due to the fact that the test data may be a little different. That is why the evaluation accuracy is not increasing any more.

This could be an explanation.

Comment: So isn't this a technical or implementation problem?

Comment: that depends on the dataset size, normalization and many parameters. If your dataset is small, then this may be the actual problem. If not, then I would experiment with model adjustments.

Comment: Train dataset has 6848 rows, dev 886 and test 3352. so i think it's small-mid size.